# Computation of Amalgamated Product $\mathbb{Z}_4 \ast_{\mathbb{Z}_2} \mathbb{Z}_6.$

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, free-groups, combinatorial-group-theory, free-product

I'm trying to compute a amalgamated product $\mathbb{Z}_4 \ast_{\mathbb{Z}_2} \mathbb{Z}_6$.

Let $\mathbb{Z}_4= \langle a\mid a^4 =1\rangle$ and $\mathbb{Z}_6 = \langle b\mid b^6 =1\rangle $, be a representations of **additive** groups $\mathbb{Z}_6$ and $\mathbb{Z}_4$.

The free group $\mathbb{Z}_4 \ast \mathbb{Z}_6$ can be write in the following form

$$
\mathbb{Z}_4 \ast \mathbb{Z}_6 = \langle  a,b\mid a^4=1,b^6=1\rangle
$$

Let, $\varphi_1 : \mathbb{Z}_2 \to \mathbb{Z}_4$, $a \mapsto a^2 $ and $\varphi_2 : \mathbb{Z}_2 \to \mathbb{Z}_6$,   $b \mapsto b^3$. Observe that, $\varphi_1$ take a element of order 2 and carry to a element of order 2, then $\varphi_1$ is injective. By the same way, we have that $\varphi_2$ is injective.

Then
$$
\mathbb{Z}_4 \ast_{\mathbb{Z}_2} \mathbb{Z}_6 =\langle  a,b\mid a^4=1,b^6=1, a^2 = b^3 \rangle = \langle  b\mid b^6 =1   \rangle. \tag{$\star$}
$$

Are my calculations correct?

**Edit**

I saw a discussion on Shaun post [Presentations of Amalgamated Free Products of Two Groups.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2749278/presentations-of-amalgamated-free-products-of-two-groups?rq=1), and I think that I understand my confusion on the notation and about my doubt on the comment below.

In fact, $\left( \star \right)$ should be written as

$$
\mathbb{Z}_4 \ast_{\mathbb{Z}_2} \mathbb{Z}_6 =\langle  a,b\mid a^4,b^6, a^2 b^{-3} \rangle = \langle  b\mid b^6   \rangle
$$

where, $a^2b^{-3}$ is a **word**.

Comment: You can check them in [GAP](https://www.gap-system.org/).

Comment: Note that a group does not *equal* any given presentation. Typically, this technicality is denoted $$G\cong\langle X\mid R\rangle.$$

Comment: Your notation does not make sense. You should pick a new letter for the generator of $Z/2$ and describe its images in $Z/4, Z/6$.

Comment: I have a doubt about this; My professor have been defined the amalgamated product of two groups $G_1$ and $G_2$ by  $ G_1 \ast_{G_0} G_2 := (G_1 * G_2)/N$ where $N$ is the normalization of the subgroup generated by the set $\{ \phi_1(g_0) = \phi_2(g_0): g_0 \in G_0\}$ , $\phi_1 : G_0 \to G_1$ and  $\phi_2 : G_0 \to G_2$.  But, for me, it make no sense, because $\phi_2(g_0) \in G_2$ and $\phi_1(g_0) \in G_1$. How could they be the same?

Comment: What makes you think the last isomorphism in ($\star$) (not equality!) is true?

Comment: I think that, by definition of relation, $a^2 b^{-3} \in \ker(f)\subset F(a,b)$ where $f: F(a,b) \to \langle a,b \rangle$ is the unique homomorphism of definition of free group.  Then $f(a^2 b^{-3}) = f (a)^2 f(b)^{-3} = 1$. By the universal property of free groups, we can "forget" the function $f$, and take just $a^2 b^{-3}$ as being equal to 1. Do the same with $a^4,b^6$, I have $a ^2 = b^3 \Rightarrow (a^2)(a^2) = b^6 = 1$.

Comment: My intuition (or lack of understanding of subject) says that the relation  $a^2 b^{-3}$ is a consequence of the relation $b^6$.

Comment: Your computation does not prove your claim. How did you get rid of the generator $a$? In fact, your group admits an epimorphism to $Z_2\star Z_3$, hence, is not abelian.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, even your **definition** of the amalgam $G={\mathbb Z}_4\star_{{\mathbb Z}_2} {\mathbb Z}_6$ is wrong. You have to give a name, say, $c$ to the generator of the amalgamated subgroup ${\mathbb Z}_2$. Then you can say that the monomorphisms ${\mathbb Z}_2\to {\mathbb Z}_4$ and ${\mathbb Z}_2\to {\mathbb Z}_6$ are given, respectively, by
$$
c\mapsto a^2, \ c\mapsto b^3. 
$$
Then you correctly identified the presentation for the corresponding amalgam as
$$
\langle  a,b\mid a^4,\ a^2b^{-3},\ b^6\rangle
$$
(no need to write $=1$). What you wrote next, however, is completely unjustified:
$$
\langle  a,b\mid a^4,b^6, a^2 b^{-3} \rangle = \langle  b\mid b^6   \rangle.
$$
Your attempted justification in the comment goes absolutely nowhere; you write:
$$
^2=^3 \Rightarrow (^2)(^2)=^6=1$$
In fact, the two implied equalities do not follow from $a^2=b^3$, but do follow from $a^4=b^6=1$. What's worse, none of this explains how did you get rid of the generator $a$! Actually, one can easily see that this simply cannot be done as one can construct an epimorphism from $G$ (with the presentation $\langle  a,b\mid a^4,b^6, a^2 b^{-3} \rangle$) to the free product
$$
H={\mathbb Z}_2\star {\mathbb Z}_3,
$$
by sending $a$ to the generator of the first free factor and $b$ to a generator of the second free factor. Since $H$ is non-abelian, so is $G$.

Answer (score -1):

You're wrong.

According to GAP:

```
gap> F:=FreeGroup(2);
<free group on the generators [ f1, f2 ]>
gap> rels:=[ (F.1)^4, (F.2)^6, (F.1)^2*(F.2)^(-3) ];
[ f1^4, f2^6, f1^2*f2^-3 ]
gap> G:=F/rels;
<fp group on the generators [ f1, f2 ]>
gap> IsCyclic(G);
false
```

That is, the group cannot be cyclic and so is not isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_6$.

---

*Inspired by @MoisheKohan's
answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4680553/104041):*

Kill $a^2$ and $b^3$ in

$$\begin{align}
G&:=\mathbb{Z}_4 \ast_{\mathbb{Z}_2} \mathbb{Z}_6 \\
&\cong\langle  a,b\mid a^4,b^6, a^2b^{-3} \rangle.
\end{align}$$

Then, homomorphically, $G$ maps onto

$$\begin{align}
H&\cong \langle a,b\mid a^2,a^4, b^3, b^6, a^2b^{-3}\rangle\\
&\cong\langle a,b\mid a^2, 1^2, b^3, 1^2, 1(1)^{-1}\rangle\\
&\cong\langle a,b\mid a^2, b^3\rangle\\
&\cong\Bbb Z_2\ast\Bbb Z_3,
\end{align}$$

which is nonabelian. Hence $G$ is nonabelian, so is not cyclic. Hence $G\not\cong\Bbb Z_6$.

Comment: . n i c e . . .

Comment: Thank you, @janmarqz. Please consider upvoting :)

Comment: well, sorry I once asked for uv, only once and never more